# Gas line tape overlap to cover all threads?

Tags: natural-gas

I am using gas line tape and it says to make a minimum of 4 wraps. The tape is 1/2" wide but the threads on the pipe are like 3/4" to 1" long. Is it correct to wrap only the section in the middle or should I cover all the threads by overlapping the tape and work my way from the end to the start of the threads, and then back again? I tried overlapping but maybe I did it wrong because I wound up with a fat area in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

I wrap so that I taper the tape thickness down towards the starting threads.

Also I wrap so that the tape is not unwound by the screwing in of the threads into the hole.

Comment: Statement #2 is _most_ critical!